# Routing Fluent Bit tcp event doesn't match to Fluent

Tags: fluentd

i’m new to Fluent and Fluent Bit.

Fluent Bit (0.13) listens to tcp and forwards to a Fluent instance (td-agent 3.2). Fluent will push it to rabbitmq. The basic process is working.

Fluent Bit generates messages like

> 2018-07-09T11:44:48+02:00    tcp.0
>   {"msg":["dev.fluent",1531129488,{"test":"woooooooo 2018-07-09
>   11:44:48"}]}

the forwarded tag is tcp.0.
Fluent expects a format like following unfortunately.

> 2018-07-10T10:15:13+02:00    dev.fluent    {"birds":"are blue
>   2018-07-10 10:15:13"}

The rabbitmq routing (tag = routing_key without any other configuration) would work properly with this ‘old’ formatting.

I didn’t find any solution to rewrite the message tag with parsers/filters. Has anyone an idea to get the routing done?

Cheers
Chris